# inserting custom css, html and js into the current page as a popup window

Tags: plugins, css, html

I am new to wordpress development and I've read the documentation on how to do what I want to do but I can't find any decent answers.

I want to make a plugin that can show a popup window when someone goes to a certain page. the info in the popup will be customizable based on what the admin wants to show but I cannot figure out how to add css and js to the page the visitor is currently on. Basically injecting html and css into the body. I'm a junior developer and I've never worked with php or wordpress before (until a week ago when my boss asked me to make this wordpress plugin) but I know JS quite well.

any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a small solution BUT its not the best instead of what you ask!

You can create an custom page template in your theme or child theme https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/#manual

And paste the code:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Alert Messages</h2>

<p>Click on the "x" symbol to close the alert message.</p>
<div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it doesn't matter where on the page the pop-up HTML goes?

- You can hook the [wp_footer action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/), which is normally called at the bottom of the page just before the `</body>` close tag. That's probably the right place to write your pop-up's div etc.
- You can add extra CSS and JavaScript to the page using [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), which you should call inside a [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook. (The JavaScript here is typically written from a wp_footer handler though, so you could equally just write the script tag when you write your pop-up HTML. But I'd use wp_enqueue_script anyway.)

Comment: thanks I'll definitely  try this.